# Can iTunes on macOS detect iPhone if the iPhone is not jailbroken?

Tags: ios, macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, macos-high-sierra

I've installed macOS High Sierra as a guest of a VirtualBox on Windows 10 Host on a normal PC.

The iPhone is detected normally on Windows host and can be detected in iTunes (Microsoft store version). The iPhone is detected in the guest OS as well in the `System Information > Hardware > USB` section of the guest OS. But it's not detected in iTunes or Xcode.

The iPhone is probably not jailbroken as I cannot find Cydia app on the search bar.

What could be the issue here? Is there any tutorial on how to get iPhone working inside a macOS virtual machine? I want to build an Xcode project from Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes can detect iPhone even if the iPhone is not jailbroken.
My iTunes inside guest OS did not detect the iPhone because there is a problem with VirtualBox USB stuff. So I fixed that by using VMware instead.